# Dynamically change size of char variable

Tags: c++

i want to use a string or char variable that size can change dynamically. don't need to specify size and in code can add a cell and insert new char into cell. i use this code for this action:
 
    `char *align_A = (char*)malloc(lenMax*sizeof(char));`
is there another way that i don't need to specify size (in here `lenMax`) and when i want add new char to array or memory, dynamically add a cell and insert char character into. can i use `string` for this action? 
for example: first add into alignA, `A` character, for next character `B` size of memory or array changed and add B into and ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you use C++ and not C, use `std::string` or `std::vector`, they'll make your life a lot easier, as they are designed especially for tasks you describe.

If you really want to stick to `char *`, then check the C-style [`realloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbebcx7d.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::string` `push_back` method for this purpose. It directly appends a new char to the end of the string. std library handles memory issues itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your array dynamically and get memory from heap. You can use `new` command or `malloc`.
It will allocate memory on the heap, but making array in normal definition will use stack memory.